# In what way is the information passed between components when using social signin with angular 2+?

Tags: angular, oauth, oauth-2.0, jwt, auth0

I am planning to support multiple login options(including social sign in with google and facebook) for my app in following way.
When user clicks on login with google/facebook ,a new window opens, user authentication completes, server returns JWT, **which I store in local storage and using a *hostlistener*, the previous window(or the parent window) knows about the successful authentication.**

This flow is working fine(with a normal server-side authentication) but I am thinking about the security concern that may arise by storing the JWT in local storage. What is the standard way of sharing authentication information when using social signin?

Is there a better way to pass the JWT/authentication details from child window(where authentication happens) to parent window? 
One more option is to use Eventemitters to pass information between the 2 components, but what is the standard way that is being used by the sites that are using social signin and jwt?

**EDIT:** I want to replicate the behavior that most sites do i.e. when the until the user is authenticated, the parent window remains still and as soon as the authentication completes and is passed onto the parent window, it redirects to let's say homepage or redirect url.

Comment: Why do you want to open a new window for authentication? It makes the user experience worse and can be problematic on mobile devices. I would not do it if there is another way and the OAuth2 authentication doesn't require it.

Comment: Because in new window, multiple login options will be possible, some of which may redirect to an outside domain(google.com for instance). Also all the sites that I see, there is implementation of social login in a new window. Plus, I am planning to provide the same authentication mechanism for my 2-3 apps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you really want to use a popup window for authentication, you can access the parent window of your application from the popup using

```
window.opener
```

The easiest way to send a token from the popup to the parent is to post a message (see the [Mozilla docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/postMessage))

```
window.opener.postMessage(messageContainingToken, window.location.origin);
```

The parent window needs to have a listener

```
window.addEventListener("message", receiveTokenMessage, false);

function receiveTokenMessage(event) {
   if (event.origin !== window.location.origin) {
       return;
   }
   let messageContainingToken = event.data;
}
```

The `messageContainingToken` can be the token itself or some more complex JSON. Then you can store the token in the SessionStorage, which is safer than the LocalStorage.

**Update** (suggestion):

I would suggest you not to use the popup window. Instead, on the login page, I would create buttons for "Login with SomeOauth2Provider". When a user clicks the button, he gets redirected to the SomeOauth2Provider website and after authentication, he gets redirected back to your Angular SPA (you provide a redirectUri). The Angular component that processes the redirectUri containing a token, would validate the token, save it to the SessionStorage and change the route to some initial view of your application.

I think it's much more user friendly to load your Angular application again after the redirect than opening a new window (which can also be disabled).

Comment: Thanks. Also would it be possible for you to share what is the most common way the sites do it? I mean almost on every third site we see social login option. Out of those the ones built using angular, how are they doing this communication. Is there a standard way to do this?

Comment: I updated the answer with info about how I would do it.

Comment: When I am using window.opener.postMessage(messageContainingToken, window.location.origin, false);, I am getting error: TypeError: Failed to execute 'postMessage' on 'Window': The provided value cannot be converted to a sequence.

Comment: The `postMessage` uses the [The structured clone algorithm](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Workers_API/Structured_clone_algorithm) for the message value serialization. It has its limitations, so you are probably sending something not compatible. You can try to use a simple string to as a value that should always be accepted.

Comment: I have tried this:  `window.opener.postMessage(JSON.stringify("someMessage"),"*",false);` 
(Passing the * in second arg)
and this:
 `window.opener.postMessage("someMessage","*",false);`
and this:
`window.opener.postMessage("someMessage","http://localhost:4200/login",false);`

Comment: You are right, the last `boolean transfer` parameter of the `postMessage` method should be omitted, then you don't get the error. I updated the answer.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest using firebase. They have packages for angular, production ready social-login implementations. Have a look: https://firebase.google.com/products/auth/

There is a nice article about authenticating users with firebase for angular applications: https://medium.com/@hellotunmbi/step-by-step-complete-firebase-authentication-in-angular-2-97ca73b8eb32

Answer (score 1):

My suggestion is to use *Centralized State Management* with *@ngrx/store* in that way you have the JWT and the user claims stored in the State of the App being possible to consume it from every part of your App.

The following links may help to kickstart:

https://auth0.com/blog/managing-state-in-angular-with-ngrx-store/

https://github.com/ngrx/platform/blob/master/docs/store/README.md

https://blog.angular-university.io/angular-ngrx-store-and-effects-crash-course/

Then you can use a **HTTPInterceptor** to add the token to the headers. If you use an OAuth library like [angular-oauth2-oidc](https://github.com/manfredsteyer/angular-oauth2-oidc) you don't have to worry about this because it comes with its own Interceptor but you should have to unprovide your own in case of having one.

`localStorage` and `sessionStorage` both extend Storage. There is no difference between them except for the intended "non-persistence" of `sessionStorage`.

That is, the data stored in `localStorage` persists until explicitly deleted. Changes made are saved and available for all current and future visits to the site.

For `sessionStorage`, changes are only available per window (or tab in browsers like Chrome and Firefox). Changes made are saved and available for the current page, as well as future visits to the site on the same window. Once the window is closed, the storage is deleted.

Web Storage (`localStorage`/`sessionStorage`) is accessible through **JavaScript** on the same domain. This means that any **JavaScript** running on your site will have access to web storage, and because of this can be vulnerable to cross-site scripting (**XSS**) attacks. **XSS**, in a nutshell, is a type of vulnerability where an attacker can inject **JavaScript** that will run on your page.

**USE COOKIES INSTEAD!!!**
**Cookies**, when used with the `HttpOnly` cookie flag, are not accessible through **JavaScript**, and are immune to **XSS**. You can also set the Secure cookie flag to guarantee the cookie is only sent over HTTPS.